# Accessing state functions from a list item on a render row nested onPress

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to access one of my actions from within the my row `onPress` function but the issue is in the `onPress` it is out of scope from the rest of the state.

My question is how do I access the state functions to call from within my `onPress` method.

```
import {planLocalesFetch, localeDelete} from '../actions';
import LocaleListItem from './LocaleListItem';
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';

class  PlanLocalesList extends Component {

            // all the state code is here 

             renderRow(planLocale) {

              let swipeBtns = [{
                text: 'Delete',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                onPress: () => {
               axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/locales/${planLocale.id}`, { params: {
                locale_id: planLocale.id }});
                this.props.planLocalesFetch(plan); // error is that this does not exist in this scope;
              }
              }];
              return (
                <Swipeout right={swipeBtns}
                  backgroundColor= 'transparent'>

                    <View>
                     <LocaleListItem planLocale={planLocale} />
                    </View>
                </Swipeout>
              )
            }

            render () {
              return (

                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                  <ListView
                    dataSource={this.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                />
                </View>

              );
            }
          }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
const plan = state.planLocales.plan
const planLocales = _.map(state.planLocales.locales, (val, uid) => {
              return { ...val, uid };
            });
            return { planLocales, plan};
          };
export default  connect(mapStateToProps, {planLocalesFetch, localeDelete})(PlanLocalesList);
```

Here is the action to fetch the data for the list.

```
export const planLocalesFetch = (plan) => {
      return (dispatch, state) => {
      if (plan) {
         state().planForm.currentPlan = plan;
      }
      var plan_id = state().planForm.currentPlan.id;
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/plans/${plan_id}`).then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: PLAN_LOCALES_FETCH, payload: response.data})
      });
      };
    };
```

The problem I am having is the `this.props.planLocalesFetch(plan);` does not exist in the nested `onPress` scope.

Comment: Can you check whether you can access to **this**?

Comment: I can't I fixed it using a then condition.

Answer (score 0):

fix using the .then statement

```
let swipeBtns = [{
  text: 'Delete',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  onPress: () => {
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/locales/${planLocale.id}`, { params: {
  locale_id: planLocale.id }}).then(() => {
    this.props.planLocalesFetch();
  })
```